# Check if the integer value of a text field is valid in a switch statement [swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I've been attempting to check if the integer value of a text field is valid in a switch statement to cover more possible cases rather having long if/elseif statements.

```
switch characterTextFields {
case Int(characterTextFields[1].text!) == nil:
    validationErrorModal(text: "Level must be a number!")
}
```

The code above prompts the following error:

> Expression pattern of type 'Bool' cannot match values of type '[UITextField]?'

characterTextFields is an array of text fields. I did research about possibly solutions which involved using let and where keywords, but wasn't able to implement correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: It makes no sense to switch on something called `characterTextFields`. The switch must be on the value to be matched against the cases. It would be easier to help you if you would tell us what the "more possible cases" are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `switch` for that, but you have to switch over that number, not over the input field:

```
switch Int(characterTextFields[1].text!) {
    case nil:
        validationErrorModal(text: "Level must be a number!")
    case 0?:  // switch over optional value
        break
}
```

Usually it is simpler to handle the optional first, e.g. :

```
guard let level = Int(characterTextFields[1].text!) else {
    validationErrorModal(text: "Level must be a number!")
    return
}
```

and then switch over the non-optional value:

```
switch level {
   case 0:
     break
   default:
     break       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you use `guard let`:

```
guard let level = Int(characterTextFields[1].text!) else {
    validationErrorModal(text: "Level must be a number!")
    return
}

// Do something with your level
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way you can achieve it:

```
switch Int(characterTextFields[1].text!) {
    case nil:
        validationErrorModal(text: "Level must be a number!")
    default:
        validationErrorModal(text: "Level is a number!")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to validate as they type.  You should implement a UITextFieldDelegate.  And then implement this in your delegate:

```
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
          //Check for illegal characters
          return (string.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789").inverted) == nil)
        }
```

This prevents any illegal entry from happening in the first place.